# Test if Range has a Name in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to determine if a range has a name and keep getting an error message.

My code looks like this:

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim sName As String

Set rCell = Range("A1")
If Not rCell.Name Is Nothing Then sName = rCell.Name
```

And produces the following error message:

Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error

I have also tried replacing the
`If Not rCell.Name Is Nothing Then sName = rCell.Name` line with `sName = rCell.Name` and even `Debug.Print rCell.Name` but keep getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Range.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.name) throws a RTE 1004 if the range is not named. One alternative is to try to assign to a `Name` object.

Note that you probably want the [`Name.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name.name) property.

```
Set rCell = Range("A1")

On Error Resume Next
Dim n As Name
Set n = Nothing ' only including in case you are planning to use this approach in a loop.
Set n = rCell.Name
On Error GoTo 0

If not n Is Nothing Then
   sName = n.Name ' Name.Name, not Range.Name
End If
```